# Sylius : Fresh install but API does not work

Tags: php, api, symfony, sylius

I am a beginner in Sylius and i'm trying to use the API, but it does not work. Each result is "404 Page not found".

Steps :

- Creating an apache2 vhost (hostname : myproject.local
- Installing Sylius (1.10) with official documentation (Project + Database + Front compilation)
- Adding some content with the admin panel
- Creating new customer from Front Office

Everything is OK but when i'm trying to create a user with the API, the response is the "Route not found (404 Not Found)" HTML page.
(This is the very first API call from the official documentation : [Sylius API doc](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/getting-started-with-sylius/using-api.html))

That is my OS details :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

I am using Apache2 and MySQL :

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2021-09-28T10:57:42

mysql  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.21.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

When i use the command :

```
php bin/console debug:router api
```

I can see 189 results, i tried some, for example :

```
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                   |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | api_doc                                                 |
| Path         | /api/v2/docs.{_format}                                  |
| Path Regex   | {^/api/v2/docs(?:\.(?P<_format>[^/]++))?$}sD            |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |
| Method       | ANY                                                     |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _api_respond: true                                      |
|              | _controller: api_platform.action.documentation()        |
|              | _format:                                                |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

URL : http://myproject.local/api/v2/docs, but the result is the same

Did i miss something ?

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but do you have `sylius_api: enabled: true` in your config files ?

Comment: Hi @ Grégoire Ducharme,
Thanks for your answer, this is not a dumb question, as a beginner I missed some points. You were right, I forgot that line.
After modifying that and generating a new pair of JWT tokens, the API works!
Thanks again !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i forgot to active the API :

As the documentation says, "*The new unified Sylius API is still under development*" so this feature needs to be enabled.

Edit *config/packages/_sylius.yaml* to add :

```
sylius_api:
    enabled: true
```

Now the API is activated, the routes no longer respond 404.

Last thing, before you can actually use the API you need to generate a JWT key pair otherwise the API calls will return "*Unable to create signed JWT from given configuration*".

To do that, use the JWT package ([Lexik Repository](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle)) :

```
php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair
```

Now everything is good you can use the API, enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks, somehow on local dev environement it is not needed to enable in _sylius.yaml